# C# How to P/Invoke with struct array in struct?

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio, struct, pinvoke

In C#, how to P/Invoke with struct array in struct?

C Lang defined struct is below...

```
struct 'OuterStruct'
  int outerId
  InnerStruct[10] innerStruct 
struct 'InnerStruct'
  int innerId
  char[32] name
```

And C Lang defined Function is:

```c
int ClangFunc(OuterStruct* arg)
```

'ClangFunc' is set values to 'arg'.

I call 'ClangFunc' from C#...

```cs
[DllImport("makefromclang.dll", EntryPoint="ClangFunc")]
public static extern int ClangFunc(IntPtr arg);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct OuterStruct
{
    public int outerId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagementType.ByValArray, SizeConst=10)]
    public InnerStuct[] innerStruct;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct InnerStruct
{
    public int innerId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagementType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=32)]
    public string name;
}

/* caller */
OuterStruct outerStruct = new OuterStruct();
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(outerStruct));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(outerStruct, ptr, false);
int result = ClangFunc(ptr);
OuterStruct resultStruct = (OuterStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(OuterStruct));
```

Call `ClangFunc` is succeeded.

Results of `OuterStruct.outerId and OuterStruct.innerStruct[0].innerId` are set collect values.(in above `resultStruct` value)

But `OuterStruct.innerStruct[0].name` is `null`, why?.

I expected ""(empty string) or any `Shift_JIS` string. There's no way to set `null` value.

Comment: Add CharSet=CharSet.Ansi to StructLayout of the InnerStruct.

Comment: The argument should be `[In, Out] ref OuterStruct arg`.  The [Out] attribute is necessary to tell the pinvoke marshaller that it needs to copy the marshalled structure content back.  The missing CallingConvention.Cdecl is highly suspicious.  None of this is exactly guaranteed to solve the problem, you'd better write some unit tests in C to ensure the function works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

The problem is that the value set in char[] is Shift_JIS charset.
When .NET converted char[] to string, it did not consider the character set.
As a result, the string value is corrupted, and the debugger seems to have a null string value.

To solve this problem, I modified the string mapped to the structure to byte[] and convert byte[] to string.

```
// [MarshalAs(UnmanagementType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=32)]
// public string name;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=32)]
public byte[] name;


string str = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS").GetString(name);
```